# Handlebars won't show one out of 6 values

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

So I'm linking in some values to an .hbs-file and most of the values is returned. But for some reason, one of the values is not returning anything. The .hbs:

```
<nav>
    <h2>Working Files</h2>
    {{#if snippets }}
        <ul>
            {{#each snippets}}
                <li class={{ this.active }}><a href={{ this.sessId }}>{{ this.name }}<span class="ft">{{ this.fileType }}</span></a>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    {{/if}}
</nav>
```

And I'm sending them in like this:

router.route("/home/:id")
    .get(restrict, function(req, res) {

```
    User.findOne({ user: req.session.Auth.username }, function(error, data) {

        Snippet.find({ postedBy: data._id}).exec()
            .then(function(data) {
                Snippet.find({ _id: req.params.id}).exec()
                    .then((snippetID) => {

// This is what I send it -------------------------------------------------
                        let context = {
                            snippets: data.map(function(snippet) { // Gets the snippet info for nav
                                return {
                                    name: snippet.title,
                                    fileType: snippet.fileName,
                                    id: "/home/" + snippet._id
                                };
                            }),

                            text: snippetID[0].snippet[0].text, // Gets the snippet-text, and writes it
                            sessionId: snippetID[0]._id, // For the CRUD to get the id
                            active: "active"
                        };

                        res.render("../views/home", context);

// ------------------------------------
                    }).catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
            }). catch(function(err) {console.log(err)});

    });
});
```

It's the **"this.active"** that holds no value at all. I've been scratching my head over and over about this, and I can't understand why that value won't follow. **All the other values do follow.** I've even tried to set the "active"-key to the same value as "id" or "text", but no luck.

**Do anyone know what the problem is?**